# Burn the [growth] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [growth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/growth) tag seems to be quite useless:

- questions that have been tagged by it have better tags already ([algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) [big-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-o))
- the tag has no single meaning; other tags vary from [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) to [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)
- just 32 questions tagged

Should we burn it?

(I noticed its little brother [growth-rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/growth-rate) which has similar attributes but wasn't quite sure whether or not I should join the two burninate requests)

Comment: I think both of them can be burnt

Comment: Cut the over[growth].

Answer (score 6):

Burninated..

[image]